# passing user data to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using nodejs, express, mongoose and passport for authentication.
I have mongoose model named User which holds user data (a lot of data).
No, I want to create a route that renders index.jade and set the user data in the template.
My route is:

```
app.get('/something', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        user: req.user || {}
    });
});
```

My template:

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
    head
    body
        script(type='text/javascript')
            window.user = #{user};
```

I have two problems with the following:

1. I don't want the client to get the whole User structure. I only need several attributes and that's all. I know from Java and from .NET that there is the term "Data Transfer Objects" that indicate an object that its purpose is to pass data to the client. What is the equivalent in node? What is the best practice in node of passing the client only the relevant data?
2. The client need the user id in order to identify the user. I don't want to pass mongo original User document _id. What can I do? Should I need to encode the id somehow?

Comment: If you look at the mongoose [findOne](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) documentation , you can see that the call takes an optional second parameter thats lists the fields you want. You could use this in your LocalStrategy to limit the number of fields in the returned object. For example `User.findOne({ username: username }, "username user_id", function (err, user) { ...`

Comment: @jimoleary: This is not the mongoose layer to decide which data I need.. This data selection is related only to the presentation layer, where I know to whom I am going to pass the data.

Comment: Who is the one that didn't understand the question and gave me -1?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `res.render` you actually don't send anything from the variables to your client except the variables you use in your template, so basically if you want to pass only the username of your user you can safely do ( with DRY improvement ) :

```
render = function(page, req, res) {
   res.render(page, { user: req.user ? req.user : {} });
};

app.get('/something', function(req, res) { render('index', req, res); });
app.get('/pageA', function(req, res) { render('pageA', req, res); });
app.get('/pageB', function(req, res) { render('pageB', req, res); });
```

**OR**

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
    head
    body
        script(type='text/javascript')
            | window.user = "#{user.username}";
```

If you want more complicated user object, you can always do :

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
    head
    body
        script(type='text/javascript')
            | window.user = { username: "#{user.username}", email: "#{user.email}" };
```

Basically this will NOT expose your `user` object to the client, just to the render function of your node viewer instance.

About the user id, you can use whatever other unique user property as username, email address, etc.

Comment: So you actually saying that there is no such thing like Data Transfer Object, and that my template should hold the client data presentation of the model?

Comment: Your `user` object will never reach your client's browser, the object is transferred only to your `jade` compiler. In the way you did that in your original question, you will expose the whole `user` object, but if you specify deep properties of the object, the whole object is never exposed!

Comment: I understand that. But this seems problematic. What if I have 3 different pages that I want to provide them user data? Then I need to duplicate my template code for constructing the user object.. About my second question about the user id, do you know how to encode the id?

Comment: Every template you render will need the data from the user. You can create a default layout template and then you will not need to replicate your script code everytime, but the ‘res.render‘ will always need `user` argument. What do you mean `encode` the id?

Comment: Then the solution you suggested is not good. I don't want to create user structure in each of my jade templates that need the user.
Please look on my second question about the user id.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the object for use on the client

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
    head
    body
        script(type='text/javascript')
            window.user = !={JSON.stringify(user)};
```

You could serialize on the server too

```
app.get('/something', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        user: JSON.stringify(req.user || {})
    });
});
```

and just assign it in the view

```
script(type='text/javascript')
    window.user = =#{user};
```

Comment: How can I pass the user Id if I don't want to expose the real id?

Comment: You could just `delete user._id`, though I'm not sure of the implications of doing that are. Are you using Mongoose? If so take a look at this [toObject](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) You can use `schema.options.toObject.transform` to define a method that removes the id, or you can just overload `toObject` itself. You could also pass in a set of options to `toObject` that will remove the `_id` from your document `doc.toObject({ hide: '_id' });`

Comment: But I need some sort of user id because I would like to change the user data for example. I don't want to use the original Id but something else generated from it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does your "User" model include your own generated id?

Comment: I have user._id property but I don;t want the client side tot know the real _id.

Comment: maybe generate your own user id or `uuid` for the `User` model. Check out https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid